# sonar runner exception Fail to download the file

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

After running sonar-runner.bat file, i am getting following exception.

Caused by: org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: Fail to download the file: http://localhost:9000/batch/sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar|dd4bcea04f99b09fb9a50e29adcbc1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Incomplete question. Not enough information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are still using the old "sonar" plugin in your build.gradle file.
I got the same error and changed to the "sonar-runner" plugin:

apply plugin: "sonar-runner"

And then the gradle task "sonarRunner" was working fine for me.